# Play Framework - Zip JSON Requests

Tags: json, playframework, websocket

I have a question for which I was not able to find sufficient information from the Play Framework's documentation. I have a JSON which is quite big and I send this JSON to a WebSocket Endpoint. I would now need to somehow zip this JSON from the client and send that to the WebSocket Endpoint. Once the server gets this zipped JSON, it unzips it and processes it. Is there any way currently to do this using any of the Play Framework's features? Or is there a library that I can look into?

I'm using Play Framework 2.1.1.

Here is what I do to send the Zipped JSON request to the server:

```
val input = Source.fromURL(getClass.getResource("/bulk_json_10000.txt")).mkString
val bulkJson: Array[Byte] = Utility.zipJson(input)
```

Just for testing purposes, I'm using a HTTP library that sends a request to the server:

```
val result = Http.postData(url, bulkJson)
  .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
  .header("Charset", "UTF-8")
  .option(HttpOptions.readTimeout(10000))
  .responseCode
logger.info("The response from the server " + result)
```

But all what I see is a 400 as the response code.

After adding the Content-Encoding header like below:

```
.header("Content-Encoding", "gzip")
```

I was able to get rid of the bad request error and now the server throws "Unexpected end of file from Server" error.

Here is what I do on the controller:

```
  def gzipTest = Action(parse.anyContent) { request =>
    println(request.body)
    Ok("Done!")
  }
```

Is there anything I'm missing? I'm not even trying to do anything on the server side with the in-coming request. Why should the server fail?

After fiddling around with GZIPing the request on the client, I added the GZipFilter to my Global.scala and I have the following error that I see is getting thrown from the server:

org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.embedder.CodecEmbedderException: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.compression.CompressionException: decompression failure (-3): not a gzip stream at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.messageReceived(HttpContentDecoder.java:116)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
            at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:459)
            at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:536)
            at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:107)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:88)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.compression.CompressionException: decompression failure (-3): not a gzip stream
            at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.compression.ZlibUtil.exception(ZlibUtil.java:31)
            at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.compression.ZlibUtil.fail(ZlibUtil.java:27)
            at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.compression.ZlibDecoder.decode(ZlibDecoder.java:152)
            at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:66)
            ... 19 more
    java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.cleanUpWriteBuffer(AbstractNioWorker.java:409)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.writeFromUserCode(AbstractNioWorker.java:127)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:99)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:36)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:725)
            at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.doEncode(OneToOneEncoder.java:71)
            at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:59)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:704)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:671)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.write(AbstractChannel.java:248)
            at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$6$$anonfun$12.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:208)
            at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$6$$anonfun$12.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:204)
            at play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumeratee$$anon$50$$anon$16$$anonfun$play$api$libs$iteratee$Enumeratee$$anon$$anon$$step$2$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Enumeratee.scala:359)
            at play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumeratee$$anon$50$$anon$16$$anonfun$play$api$libs$iteratee$Enumeratee$$anon$$anon$$step$2$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Enumeratee.scala:359)
            at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.liftedTree2$1(Future.scala:253)
            at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:249)
            at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:249)
            at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:29)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: In the client request, try adding the header gzip: `.header("Content-Encoding", "gzip")`

Comment: I sort of did that and ran into the following error: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server

Comment: From the error "not a gzip stream" it looks like your method zipJson is not compressing it as a GZIP but as something different

Comment: I checked my function that Gzip's and UnGzip's the String back and forth. It works. But when I send that to the server, it fails.

Comment: Check the following code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885825/play-framework-zipped-byte-stream-handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play Framework 2.2.x [supports Gzip](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/GzipEncoding) directly. For your version you can take a look to [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106504/gzip-the-response-body-in-playframework-2-0). As explained there, if Play is behind a front end, you can just perform the gzip/gunzip in the front end.

Comment: But Play uses Netty server, can't I configure something in the Netty server to achieve compression and decompression?

Comment: As described in the [Play Issue tracking](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/375), the support integrated with Netty comes in the 2.2.x.

If you have a prior 2.x version and you don't want to update to the last stable, you could  just apply the commit changes they did for supporting it: [Here](https://github.com/wpraet/Play20/commit/bab79803f2a5d7f8f41177e85eefc95f4087bb1c).

Comment: Thanks for that. In the Stack Overflow thread that you referred, I see that one of the user has offered some code that actually gzip's the response back to the client. My requirements is that I want to do it both the ways, once when the request is sent to the server and second when the response is sent to the client. How can I do that when sending the JSON request to the server? I have zipped the JSON request and I have it as a Byte[Array]. How can I send this across in a normal HTTP Post request to the Play framework server? I have updated my post with what I have done so far.

Comment: Gzip the client request doesn't involve Play at all. play should only gunzip the request and afterwards gzip the response. For these two purposes just modify the Play Framework file from the commit (linked in the previous answer) and use approach described in the Gzip documentation for Play 2.2.x

From the client side, you can test if Play Framework is handling correctly your gzipped request using curl: `curl -X POST --header Content-Encoding:gzip --data-binary @sample.txt.gz localhost:9000/wherever`

Comment: In your example., the curl uses a file to send the data, but in my scenario, I use a String that is converted to a Byte Array and that byte array becomes the body. How different is this to the gzipped file. I'm terribly confused.